# make sql subqueries stop complaining about duplicate columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so suppose I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM k JOIN j ON k.id = j.aid) k
```

suppose k and j have two columns with the same name, this entire query will complain with the duplicate columns error....

while simply executing `SELECT * FROM k JOIN j ON k.id = j.aid` will execute just fine despite the duplicate columns....

I know that you can use USING in the subquery to specify which column to use in case of duplicates, but is there a way to specify the query so that it'll automatically pic a specific column (whether randomly or using whatever rule) to use in case of duplicates without me having to manually specify them?

ie do this without modifying the subquery (SELECT * FROM k etc) and only modify the superquery (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...) and make it as abstract as possible so that it'll work regardless of what the subquery is

Comment: I agree with @JoeStefanelli. It's not one of the best practices to use `SELECT *` -- even when there are times that you need all the columns.. But, taking a shot at the matter at hand.. Have you tried `SELECT COUNT(1) ...`? One reason you get an error on column ambiguity is that when you enclosed your subquery and treated it as a table, you somewhat triggered an enforcement of rules. Similar to how we can't add two columns of the same name when we create new tables. I'm not sure how you can get your query to not throw an error the way it's currently built..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The simplest solution in this example would be to replace * with 1 in the subquery. Is the replacement of a single character really so problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM k JOIN j ON k.id = j.aid
```

The duplicate column in a sub-query happens in other RDBMS too.

personally, why do you have id columns in both tables? And not kid, jid. Per table this may be DRY and OO thinking, but utterly useless for SQL. See the bunfights at ["Why is naming a table's Primary Key column “Id” considered bad practice?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114728/5905)

Comment: because the subquery may have group bys in them and SELECT COUNT(*) will instead do a COUNT(*) by the groups rather than the total number of rows

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: you won't have `SELECT *` in that case, will you?